# Using resources outside of Xna's "Game" class

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a static class that will hold all my default resources for my game like all the possible fonts and using them in my classes.

for example:
I want to create a DefaultResources static class that will hold a SpriteFont list and in each element of the list there will be stored a different font from my resources.
My problem is that i have to use the ContentManager class which is found inside my "Game1" class which inherits from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, but i need to use it outside of this class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to make your class static, but here's solution to your problem. Have your resource class expose a public method that you can use to pass the content manager.

```
static class DefaultResourceManager
{
    private static ContentManager Manager;

    public static void Initialize(ContentManager manager)
    {
         Manager = manager;

         // Load resources and export them as public properties / methods
    }
}
```

Then in your game:

```
class MyAwesomeGame : Game
{
    public override void LoadContent()
    {
        DefaultResourceManager.Initialize(this.content);
    }
}
```

If you choose not to use a static class (which is always better):

```
class DefaultResourceManager
{
    private ContentManager manager;

    public DefaultResourceManager(ContentManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;     
        // Load resources and export them as public properties / methods
    }
}

class MyAwesomeGame : Game
{
    private DefaultResourceManager manager;

    public override void LoadContent()
    {
        this.manager = new DefaultResourceManager(this.content);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how the hell i did not think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only that list you don't need a whole class, you can simply declare your `List<SpriteFont>` in your `Game1` class and set it as `static`, so you can access it from wherever you want. IMHO